# How to translate this old saying into Chinese?

Tags: translation

I read about [this saying](http://qr.ae/7b8UIl) today and I am wandering how can I translate this into Chinese?

> reading novels, you live a thousand times, but only once otherwise.

Comment: with the help of iciba翻译（with some modifications)： 读小说，你活一千次，但否则的话只有一次，

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference:

> 你会在小说阅读中获得一千次生命，而非仅有一次。